# What is the purpose of anti-skid surge accumulator in a 777-300?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-systems

What is the purpose of the anti-skid surge accumulator in a Boeing 777-300?

What would happen if it were not present and why is it only meant for the left landing gear wheel assembly?

Comment: Is it homework? When you ask for help on homework, you need to show you made a significant effort, and you were able to get some elements, but not enough, to understand the question asked. We do not do homework from scratch.

Comment: @mins nah its not homework .

Comment: Looks like you missed part 1 of your question. Having them numbered that way may cause some (or many) to think they're homework questions...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework with no effort to reformat, and no effort to partially answer. You may edit your question so that it looks more motivated by personal interest.

Comment: @FreeMan I thought that, too, at first, but I think "part 1" is intended to be the question title.

Comment: @Squareoot This question is now the #1 Google hit. #2 is unrelated (it's about a surge suppressor.) #3 might have something useful, but it's about the KC-135, not the 773. #4 is a syndication of this question. Apparently [Otto](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/322/otto-the-autopilot) reposts our questions on [p3air.com](https://aviationnews.p3air.com/what-is-the-purpose-of-anti-skid-surge-accumulator/)

Comment: @reirab i am a Trainee technician.New to the field.. just started working on B777 with no prior experience. Spend most of my time studying manuals. Thats where i got the question from.  I can't ask any superior because they aren't that interesed about what and why . Got to ask someoone.

Comment: @Pritam Ah, ok, thanks for clarifying. Welcome to Aviation.SE! I hope someone here is able to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

> When an aircraft touches the ground, brakes are applied to decelerate the aircraft. To execute this
> on an efficient manner, an anti-skid system is installed. This makes it possible for the aircraft to perform
> a stop with maximal deceleration and minimal wear of the tires. In this way the aircraft can
> come to a safe stop without unnecessary maintenance.

Further info: https://anoukaviation.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/project-report-landing-gear.pdf (search for skid)

> The anti-skid surge accumulator absorbs brake release surges from the left normal anti-skid valve module.
>
> The right normal antiskid valve module does not need an antiskid surge accumulator because the right hydraulic system reservoir is very near to the right normal antiskid valve module.

From: http://www.plane.cc/html/ziliao/jiwu/2011/0426/23491_33.html